# Add a method to classes with a decorator

Tags: python, class, decorator

How can I add a method to a class with a decorator in Python? My goal is to have classes that use my decorator have a method available.

Here is a simplified example. I want `instance.dec_added_func()` to return `'X'`:

```
>>> def myFunction():
...   return 'X'
... 
>>> myFunction()
'X'
>>> def myDecorator(cls):
...   cls.dec_added_func = myFunction
... 
>>> @myDecorator
... class MyClass(object):
...   a = 'A'
... 
>>> instance = MyClass()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I know that this could be accomplished with subclassing a base class, but I want to be able to do it with a decorator.

Comment: The decorator function needs to return the class it was passed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Have `myDecorator` return the class object that it is passed:

   ```
   def myDecorator(cls):
       cls.dec_added_func = myFunction
       return cls
   ```

   Otherwise, the decorator will return `None` by default and you will get a `TypeError` whenever you do `MyClass()` for trying to call `None`.
2. Make `myFunction` accept a `self` argument:

   ```
   def myFunction(self):
       return 'X'
   ```

   This will be passed implicitly whenever you call it on an instance of your class.

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> def myFunction(self):
...     return 'X'
...
>>> def myDecorator(cls):
...     cls.dec_added_func = myFunction
...     return cls
...
>>> @myDecorator
... class MyClass(object):
...     a = 'A'
...
>>> instance = MyClass()
>>> instance.dec_added_func()
'X'
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

For a short method, you can also consider using a lambda if you think it's more readable:

```
def myDecorator(cls):
    cls.dec_added_func = lambda self: 'X'
    return cls
```

Another example that adds the `==` operator to a class that has a `value` field:

```
def equals(cls):
    cls.__eq__ = lambda self, other: self.value == other.value
    return cls
```

Comment: This goes against PEP8 and will cause these methods to be named with a generic `<lambda>`, which is painful to display and debug.